# visual studio code intellisense not working in autocompleted function call in javascript files

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I've been trying to migrate from Atom to visual studio code as I've heard that node.js is supported better, however after trying it for a while, I realised that intellisense fails when typing the arguments in an autocompleted function call, as you can see in the picture below.

[image: First attempt]

[image]

As you can see in the first screenshot, the intellisense doesn't work and the text is highlighted automatically after autocompleting the log() function. However, in the second screenshot, I tabbed out of the highlighted text field, navigated back in and intellisense is functional. Is there a workaround, or do I have to wait before it is fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing this issue in the future, I have found a solution in an obscure forum. All you have to do is open the command palette (ctrl+shift+p), type "preferences: open settings (json)" and add "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false.